# Stream timers across multiple android devices

Tags: streaming

I have seen multiple posts with streaming Video or Audio in multiple devices. However I want to stream multiple timers across multiple android devices. Ideally is to have same timer running on different devices. Timer can be set by some app or in-build timer app.

Is there way to achieve this ? Currently I can think of having some kind of app which shares screens on multiple devices. However such apps are either paid or do not work properly. Is there free and open source alternative ?

It will be something like master-slave kind of setup, where one device control the time and other just display it.

Answer (score 0):

You are making this overly complicated IMO. There is no need for designing a full fledged distributed system for such a simple task that can be done on the web. Just go to [Tickcounter.com](https://www.tickcounter.com/timer), sign up for a free account and create your custom timers on any device. Copy that link on your phone and create a desktop shortcut. If you're feeling fancy, create a web wrapper around it.

Comment: Hi, for this my all devices should always be connected to internet plus I can't change time once I have created such timer.

Comment: If not internet, how else do you plan on creating such a setup? Well writing a website for timers is pretty easy, host it on one of your devices locally and you can access it from devices on the same network. If you want a ready-made solution, I'm afraid you won't find one.